# What would be the most appropriate data structure given these requirements?

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures

We are building Search API in our company for some of our entities - *events*, *leagues* and *sports* each of which has name property and we have difficulties implementing business requirements.

**TL;DR;** What will be the data structure addressing these business requirements better than basic Red-Black tree does?

#### What we are the business requirements?

1. Data structure needs to be sorted so following requirements are easier for implementation therefore insertion should not break this property.
2. Data structure needs to hold information about it's entities, so node key(entity's name property) will be used for searching, but the node needs to hold all the entities with name property **starting with** node key value.
3. Data structure needs to support deletion by id. Id is also a property of all entities.
4. It needs to support index search (up to 3 characters) so if someone searches for "aaa" every node with key between "aaa**a..**" and "aaa**z**" should appear. (ex. query = "aaa", index = "aaa", "aaab", "aaaab", "aaaz", result should be "aaa", "aaab", "aaaab").
5. We need to search by localized node key.

#### What we have done so far?

We started our first iteration using built-in red-black tree (SortedSet in C#) and for nodes we had structure that holds the name property of the entity and all related events to that name property. And with one helper method we satisfied business requirements (1), (2) and (4).

As our second iteration we had to support deletion so we created a map(Dictionary) of entity id's to references to entity objects put into the SortedSet. We do that because our request for deletion is only by id and we cannot recreate entity from id, so at addition we need to create such map. (maybe augumentation can help?) With this we secured requirement (3).

Now we need to support (5) however, with every iteration (business requirement we receive) it is getting harder and harder to implement and I almost feel like we need to change our data structure in order to address business criteria better.

#### Whats the problem with the localization?

We can create new SortedSet and re-use the implementation, but this comes with huge trade off. Let me elaborate.

We have 100 of clients, each of which has like 7-8 supported languages, languages in our system are unique per client so translations for one customer does not interfere with another (if someone wants to call it Soccer rather than Football, fine let it be.), besides that we have base languages (global for every client) which are basically default settings for newly create languages, so we can safely say that very large portion of client specific language (lets say english) is the same as the base one. Having said all of that, if we want to have accurate search for each client and locale individually we need to have index for each client and locale individually which on the other hand introduces **massive** amounts of duplication.

#### What I have thought so far?

I am not an expert in data structures myself, but I really want to make this right. Of course everything is possible with enough coding and hardware, but thats not the point.

I thought about implementing some binary tree (could be AVL, Red-Black, 2-3-4 etc.) and augment it to meet the requirements better than built in SortedSet does. This will hopefully solve a lot of the issue and workarounds we had to make so far and as I said address future requirements better so implementation is faster and more accurate, ***however*** like I said I am not an expert in data structures myself and sadly I am unable to map these business requirements to some data structure for the time frame I have, so without further a due, do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: I may have missed an important part, but all of the above is supported conveniently by a relational database. Insertion, deletion, indexing, non-redundancy through normalization and much more. On top you have a nice flexible query language, scalability, fault-tolerance,...

Comment: @SaiBot yes I know, but this is how business wants it - in-memory search API, also I know that services like ES can solve this but yet again they want us to build ourselves something.

Comment: To build something complicated from scratch instead of using an existing mature technology sounds very odd to me from a business perspective. What do you mean by "build ourselves"? No external libraries besides standard library?

Comment: No, its more like, no external proprietary services.

Comment: Sorry if this is not what you want but there are non-proprietary (public domain) in-memory databases, e.g., [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite).

Comment: How many entities are we talking about?

Comment: @juvian 1 000 000 to 10 000 000

Comment: An index for each client doesn´t sound bad, it even allows distributing the system. The duplication would only be the index structure, as the entities should not be repeated. If you want however to do all in a single machine with all data on memory, an option could be storing pointers instead of entities in your nodes, so you can have multiple entity pointers in the tree (one for soccer, another for football). You would need to change deletion, either by storing the reference to all places or just the reference to the entity and then search and delete from tree all the localized keys.

Comment: Your first "business" requirement, that the data structure be sorted, is inappropriate. It's possible, even likely, that a sorted data structure is not the most efficient or effective way to do this. You've turned a possibly invalid implementation decision into a business requirement, thereby arbitrarily eliminating a large number of possible solutions.

Comment: As @SaiBot pointed out, you've described requirements that databases do well. If for some reason management wants an in-memory solution, there are in-memory databases such as SQLite. That said, if management is making implementation decisions, you probably should be looking for another job. This can only end badly.

Comment: @JimMischel, yea my last day is last day of this month I just wanted to make this right :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion here would be for your primary data structure to be a dictionary, keyed by product id, and the value is the product data. That gives you very quick insertion, and removal by product id.

For searching, provide a separate data structure that contains the product names and associated product ids.

```
class IndexEntry
{
    string ProductName;
    string ProductId;  // or int, if ProductId is an integer
}
```

Since you allow customer-specific names, you'll have to add all those customer names to this index. Not a problem, but when you remove something by ID, you'll also have to remove the associated items from the other data structure. This will require a sequential search of the name index data structure to ensure that you get all the names associated with a particular product. That could be expensive, even if you use a tree structure.

To speed things up, you could have a "deleted" flag for those index entries, and then rebuild the structure periodically to remove the deleted items. That way, a deletion just requires a sequential scan. That's less than ideal, but if insertions and deletions are infrequent, quite acceptable.

The key, though, is to make your primary data structure that holds the product information indexed by product id. You can then build secondary indexes any way you want.